# How to process 20k SVG files with Inkscape CLI mode ? (align and merge objects)

Tags: bash, optimization, svg, inkscape

I'm **generating ~20 000 files** based on a template. Those files contains 2 objects:

1. a Chinese character (`hanzi`) ;
2. its pronunciation (`pinyin`).

This part is working nicely, then I to:

- align `hanzi` to the left ;
- align `pinyin` to the right
- merge `hanzi` and `pinyin`

  - this imply to **first convert from `<svg:text>` to `<svg:path>`**

with the following options:

```bash
inkscape -f file.svg \
  --select=hanzi --verb=AlignHorizontalLeft --verb=EditDeselect \
  --select=pinyin --verb=AlignHorizontalRight --verb=EditDeselect \
  --select=hanzi --select=pinyin \
  --verb=AlignVerticalCenter --verb=SelectionUnion \
  --verb=FileSave --verb=FileQuit
```

The throttle is that I **open/close `Inkscape` for each file**.

N.B.: I'm using `Inkscape` `0.48.4 r9939` (Jan 22 2014)

#### Question

1. Is there a way to process several files in one `Inkscape` instance ?
2. What is the alternative to the `Align*` verbs as they are not available in `inkscape --verbs-list` ?

#### Reference

- [original source code](https://github.com/edouard-lopez/Hanzi-Pinyin-Font/blob/98a7fe3d7dbf0a5e492658feec28e6a513a89b17/bin/svg-text2svg-font.bash)

Comment: Do you use option `-z`?

Comment: last time I checked it was incompatible with the use of `--verb`

Comment: confirmed, it's not compatible. Nothing happen when I add this option

Comment: Same goes for `--shell` it's incompatible with verbs `AlignHorizontalLeft` `EditDeselect` `AlignHorizontalRight` `AlignVerticalCenter` `FileSave` `FileClose` which require GUI, even in current trunk (`Inkscape 0.91pre2 r (Oct 25 2014)`)…

Comment: I would wonder if you could not do with XSL. It would depend on the last step. Is that wrapping into a g and setting vertical alignment or is that some conversion the graphical engine needs to make.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know Inkscape at all, but I think your issue is that it is all too slow - though you do not say that explicitly. Anyway, you could maybe try `GNU Parallel` like this:

```
parallel -j 8 ./process {} ::: *.svg
```

That will keep 8 jobs running in parallel till all 20,000 files are processed. The `{}` is short-hand for the filename, and the list of filenames is given after the `:::`. If there are too may files for your command line, you can feed them in like this on `stdin`:

```
find . -name "*.svg" | parallel -j 8 ./process {}
```

Then you would wrap your Inkscape command in a script called `process` and make it executable (using `chmod +x process`) and make it take a single parameter - i.e. the filename.

I guess it is worth a try anyway - use a small COPIED folder of samples till you get confident with `GNU Parallel`.

Comment: This should increase the process a bit, but I reckon a huge amount of the time spent is to load Inkscape and its extensions.

Comment: no not solving the issue, please read the question more carefully